# Do category names get serialized with encodeWithCoder style marshalling?

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that is storing some data using the Cocoa/ObjC `initWithCoder / encodeWithCoder` style marshaling. Over the life of the app one of the classes that has been removed is an `NSDate+Utils` category.

The question is - if an `NSDate+Utils` is serialized to disk, and then deserialized with a later codebase when `NSDate+Utils` no longer exists; will it come back as an `NSDate`, or will it crash??

Answer (score 0):

It won't crash. You just need to check whether it's nil. If that' nil, then just skip it, otherwise populate the data to your property. By the way, there is nothing to do with the codebase. It's just whether that local data being stored in the device. Codes are just things that tell device what or how to do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small program to test this.  Categories seem to get written as the base class - I assume as long as they don't add fields and/or mess with the `withCoder` methods.